# Opening any file in windows explorer takes a long time

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

When I double click any file on my windows explorer it takes a long time to open.

It doesn't matter if it's a pdf, image or txt file.

Also if I right click the file and select "open with" it takes a long time to open.

Even when I select windows icons such as "Devices and printers" it takes a long time.

Any Ideas?

Comment: 1. Maybe your HDD Is dying so it's slowing down. 2. Try defragmentation (just search in start menu) 3. Have you tried restarting the pc? 4. If it's not a big hassle a fresh install of windows. Let me know if any of the above solve your issue.

Comment: disable Windows Defender and look if Explorer is faster. if yes, use a different 3rd party antivirus suite

Comment: @SamMousa - it's a relatively new pc - installed it in the last 12 month.

I have a clone of it at the office and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Windows 
But as other suggested turn off windows defender and check it.

Also try disabling search index 
That is very likely the cause.

Go to task manager and try seeing any abnormal behaviour or CPU/memory or storage usage

Comment: Tried it - it didn't help.

No cpu spikes or memory spikes. Just slow.

And it's a kick ass machine - I7 6 cores with 32 gb of ram and ssd drive

Comment: @Noam want my true advice as a programmer? Don't bother. Back up and format.

Comment: I just hate the setup - it always takes days to get back up to speed :)

Comment: @Noam true but that's windows for you :)